# Telnet to port 80 is not showing results

Tags: http, telnet

I'm trying to a test request/response to `www.google.com` on port `80` as below :

```
$ telnet www.google.com 80
```

After that I typed in :

```
GET‌ / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
```

But nothing happens!

[image]

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As laid out in [RFC 2616, section 5](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) (see the request syntax documentation near the top), there needs to be a single empty line to indicate that you finished the request headers, otherwise the server will continue to expect more input.

Try this:

> GET / HTTP/1.1 <kbd>Enter</kbd>
>   Host: www.google.com <kbd>Enter</kbd>
>   <kbd>Enter</kbd>